# While Using CDN to fetch ReactJS Module Bundle, is NodeJS still needed to be installed on the server (Apache)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I'm learning ReactJS, got confused about the working of CDN to deliver React Dependencies using `<Script>` tag in head section of HTML. Is the NodeJS still needed in the server (for example, on a production site, is NodeJS still required for React Web App (Apache server) or just CDN script will work)?

Thank You So Much!

Comment: I'm also still learning and struggling to setup ReactJS in Visual Studio 2022 - Aspnetcore project. But from what I can tell, you only need to run server site NodeJS when using React development version. Those server site script helps in setting up environment variable (ex: process.env.NODE_ENV).

Comment: @Ariwibawa - Meaning, we still need NodeJS on Apache server in production and the dependencies to run the React app will be imported from CDN?

Comment: You don't need apache server in production it's just for development (react.development.js). And about dependencies. I've just decided to stop using react, and still looking for another JS UI framework. The last error was "Uncaught Error: Module name 'object-assign' has not been loaded yet for context", even though I've added that object-assign JS. Hopefully you have more luck than me.

Comment: You only need Node on the server if you're using features like [SSR](https://medium.com/jspoint/a-beginners-guide-to-react-server-side-rendering-ssr-bf3853841d55). If your project is simply static files (JS, HTML, CSS, etc) then you don't need it